# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type with actual type

Tags: haskell

Hey so I was learning Haskell in class and I was given the problem of removing all instances of something from a list. This is my go at it but I run into this error that I'm not sure I follow.

```
--delete element from list 
removeElement :: [a] -> [a]
removeElement x [] = []
removeElement x aList =
    if (head aList) == x
        then removeElement x (tail aList)
        else aList
```

The error I receive is this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[[a]] -> [[a]]'
                with actual type `[a]'
    Relevant bindings include
      removeElement :: [a] -> [a] (bound at hwmk3.hs:8:1)
    The equation(s) for `removeElement' have two arguments,
    but its type `[a] -> [a]' has only one
```

I'm guessing that the syntax is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The signature says your function has one argument, and the equation says it has two. Mind you, this *can* have sense in Haskell, just probably not what you need here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

Your type annotation indicates that your function will receive a single list parameter and return a list, whereas the implementation indicates that you should receive two parameters, the first of which is a single element.

Furthermore, since you are using `==` to compare, you'll need to make sure your type is of the `Eq` typeclass.

Your type annotation should probably look like this:

```haskell
removeElement :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

You can also simplify things by taking advantage of pattern matching. You don't need to use `head` and `tail` if you define your function like this:

```haskell
removeElement x aList@(y:ys) =
  if y == x
    then removeElement x ys
    else aList
```

*However*, there is a logic error in your conditional statement. Since this sounds like homework, I'll leave it to you to find the answer. Hint, try `removeElement 3 [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Ah that is more of the function I was going for I just was not aware of the syntax. Thank you! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you had omitted the explicit type declaration of your function, Haskell would have inferred something like `a -> [a] -> [a]`. In fact, it *still* infers that, which is why it is complaining that it does not agree with your stated type.

The problem reported by Haskell is this. Looking at your second equation, which desugars to

```
removeElement x = \aList -> if (head aList) == x then removeElement x (tail aList) else aList
```

a few things are "obvious":

1. `x :: [a]` as the argument to `removeElement`.
2. The lambda expression has type `t -> v` for some types `t` and `v`.

But we've already said that `removeElement :: [a] -> [a]`, so can we come up with values for `t` and `v` such that `[a] ~ t -> v`? Maybe. Let's keep inferring types.

`t` is the type of `aList`, which we can infer from `head aList == x` to be `[[a]]`. Skipping the recursive call for now, we can also see that `aList` is the return value, so `v` is also `[[a]]`. Thus, `t -> v` is really `[[a]] -> [[a]]`.

Can we match a value of type `[[a]] -> [[a]]` with `[a]`?

No, which is why you get the exact error message you do.

Answer (score 0):

Your type signature should be

```
removeElement :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Also, it looks like your function does not do what you think it will do.